# Changing character in a string to two characters

Tags: c, string, visual-studio

Hello I have a problem with strchr() because yea it will return the pointer to the first occurance of the character but how do I get the index from that to be able to change it? and how can I change one character to two characters?
So I need to change every 'x' in the src to 'ks' in the dest.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void antikorso(char *dest, const char *src) {
    strcpy(dest, src);
    if (strchr(dest, 'x')) {

    }
    printf("\n%s", dest);
}

int main(void) {

    const char *lol = "yxi yxi";
    char asd[1000];
    antikorso(asd, lol);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `strcpy`, copy `src` to `dest` character by character in a loop and when you encounter character  `x` while copying characters from `src`, instead of `x`, add `ks` in `dest`.

Comment: Your function has the same problem as `strcpy` and so many others -- it is insecure! If you write functions like these, learn from the errors others have made in the past, and provide the size of the buffer (`dest`), too. Check for not exceeding this size, terminate the resulting buffer (string) with 0 even if you need to truncate and best provide some return value to tell how many bytes you have written...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
void antikorso(char *dest, const char *src) {
    const char *p = src;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; *p != '\0'; i++, p++) {
        if (*p != 'x') {
           dest[i] = *p;
        } else {
           dest[i++] = 'k';
           dest[i] = 's';
        }
    }
    dest[i] = '\0'; 
    printf("\n%s", dest);
}
```

Comment: I would not mix accessing arrays via pointer and index at the same time; actually, you do not need p and i at all, you can just increment src and dst appropriately...

Answer (score 1):

following lines of code might be helpful :

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void antikorso(char *dest, const char *src) {
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(src);i++)
        {
          if (src[i] == 'x')) {
           dst[j]='k';
           j++;
           dst[j] = 's';
           j++;
           }
           else
           {
             dst[j] = stc[i];
             j++;
           }
           i++;
        }
        dst[j] = '\0';
        printf("\n%s", dest);
        return dest;
    }

    int main(void) {

        const char *lol = "yxi yxi";
        char asd[1000];
        antikorso(asd, lol);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not need the index, just a pointer. The "index" would be the offset from the beginning, so `dest[i]`, which is the same as `dest + i`, which is the address of `dest`, plus `i` characters further. So you can use:

```
    char *cp;
    if (cp=strchr(dest, 'x')) {
       *cp= 'y';
```

But if you do want the index, it is just

```
   if (cp=strchr(dest, 'x')) {
       int i = cp - dest;
```

Comment: Except `int` is not a proper type to use for representing an address.

Comment: @Lundin, it is not an address, it is an index.

Comment: Which, theoretically, may be of the same size as an address and not fit inside an `int`.

Comment: @Lundin, how to deal with negative indexes?

Comment: See my answer. Negative indices shouldn't be possible unless something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers not being incorrect, just want to address an important issue: You are not safe from undefined behaviour by writing past the end of your target buffer (same problem as with so many stdlib functions like `strcpy` or `strcat` nowadays considered insecure)! So I strongly recommend modifying your function signature (if you have the freedom to do so):

```
size_t antikorso(char* dest, size_t length, const char* src)
// ^^                           ^^                               
{
    char* d = dest;
    char* end = d + length;
    for(; *src; ++src, ++d)
    {
        // not much different than the other answers, just the range checks...
        if(d == end)
            break;
        *d = *src;
        if(*d == 'x')
        {
            *d = 'k'
            if(++d == end)
                break;
            *d = 's';
        }
    }
    // now null-terminate your string;
    // first need to get correct position, though,
    // in case the end of buffer has been reached:
    d -= d == end;
    // this might possibly truncate a trailing "ks";
    // if not desired, you need extra checks...
    *d = 0;
    return d - dest;
}
```

The return value does not add anything to safety, but prevents you from having to call `strlen` on the output, once written...

Comment: yea i'm not allowed to modify it but like its interesting could u explain why these str functions are "insecure"? and how does adding size_t to the function prevent it?

Comment: @michael Very simple example: `char buffer[4]; strcpy(buffer, "Aconcagua");` -- what is going to happen? Answer: undefined behaviour as writing beyound array bounds -- application might crash (then you are rather lucky), but also run into very subtle and difficult to find bugs as you might be overwriting memory used for totally different purposes... By providing the buffer size, you can check within your function if you exceed the buffer and handle it appropriately. Sure, if a  bad (too small!) size is provided, same can happen, but this is not in the responsibility of the function any more...

Answer (score 1):

If `strchr` returns a valid address, you can use pointer arithmetic to get the index, by subtracting the "base address" - that is, the pointer to the first element of the array.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h> // NULL, ptrdiff_t

const char* result = strchr(dest, 'x');

if ( result != NULL) 
{
  ptrdiff_t index = result - dest;
  ... // do stuff with index
}
```

`ptrdiff_t` is a standard C integer type suitable for expressing the result of pointer arithmetic.